# How do I fix Notepad++ after attempting to add PoormansTSQLFormatter as a plugin?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I have recently attempted to add the Poor Mans Tsql Formatter plugin to Notepad++ on my Windows 8 machine, but this failed because I don't have .Net 3.5 installed and don't have the necessary permissions to download it.

Now, whenever I start up Notepad++, it attempts to download .Net 3.5 and produces the error message:-

> A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll is not compatible with the current
>   version of Notepad++.
>
> Do you want to remove this plugin from the plugins directory to
>   prevent this message from the next launch?

Clicking Yes or No doesn't make any difference. The Poor Mans TSQL Formatter check box in the Plug-In manager is cleared, and re-installing Notepad++ doesn't get rid of this error.

Does anyone know what I should attempt? This isn't the worst catastrophe that ever happened, but is getting a little irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to go into the Notepad++ plugins folder and delete the file. It should be under the install location something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins". Delete PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll if it's in there.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest to get rid of the PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll in the Notepad++ plugins folder to solve the issue. Instead of deleting it, you can also move it to the disabled (plugins) subfolder.

You may also have to remove poormans config file, which is (depending on your installation) usually located under
C:\Users_YOU_USER_NAME_HERE_\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config

BTW: From PluginManagerPlugins.xml you can learn which files to delete in case of an uninsall:

```
<plugin name="Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter">
    <unicodeVersion>1.5.1</unicodeVersion>
    <description>A simple SQL formatter performing full multi-batch T-SQL formatting (individual statements, stored procedures, any DML, any DDL) with numerous formatting options.</description>
    <author>Tao Klerks</author>
    <homepage>http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx</homepage>
    <sourceUrl>https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter</sourceUrl>
    <latestUpdate>Numerous enhancements, a couple of minor bugfixes; most notable: remembers cursor position from before formatting.</latestUpdate>
    <install>
        <unicode>
            <download>http://www.architectshack.com/GetFile.aspx?File=SqlFormatterNppPlugin.1.5.1.zip&amp;Page=PoorMansTSqlFormatter</download>
            <copy from="PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll" to="$PLUGINDIR$\" validate="true"/>
            <copy from="PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\LinqBridge.dll" to="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\" validate="true"/>
            <copy from="PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\fr\PoorMansTSqlFormatterPluginShared.resources.dll" to="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\fr\" validate="true"/>
            <copy from="PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\es\PoorMansTSqlFormatterPluginShared.resources.dll" to="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\es\" validate="true"/>
            <copy from="PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\PoorMansTSqlFormatterLib.dll" to="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\" validate="true"/>
            <copy from="PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\PoorMansTSqlFormatterPluginShared.dll" to="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\" validate="true"/>
        </unicode>
    </install>
    <remove>
        <unicode>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\es\PoorMansTSqlFormatterPluginShared.resources.dll"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\es"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\fr\PoorMansTSqlFormatterPluginShared.resources.dll"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\fr"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\LinqBridge.dll"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\PoorMansTSqlFormatterLib.dll"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin\PoorMansTSqlFormatterPluginShared.dll"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin"/>
            <delete file="$PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll"/>
            <delete file="$CONFIGDIR$\Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter.ini.xml"/>
        </unicode>
    </remove>
</plugin>
```

So, basically, delete:

- the folder $PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin
- the file   $PLUGINDIR$\PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll
- the file   $CONFIGDIR$\Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter.ini.xml

Answer (score 1):

You should Try Complete Installation of Notepad ++

1. Go to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++` You can see `uninstall.exe` double click on this file. follow the procedure to uninstall. You see only some files has been removed some are remaining.
2. Go (windows+R) type `regedit` Go to File - Export - Save the Backup of Registry. This is good habbit before you to changes in registry.

**Note: Before careful while deleting the Registry entries**

3. Delete all registry entries of the program/Folder with Name of Notepad++.
   Better you delete Notepad++ folder itself.

   > ```
   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Notepad++\
   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Notepad++\
   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\
   > ```

In Registry Press F3. You get a prompt of Find Next. Prefer below image
[image]

Type `Notepad++` Click on `Find Next` Button. You Find the entries of Notepad++ **Only delete the entries which it shows.**

Again Do **F3** and search and delete the only the Entries. Remove all the entry in same way.

4. Delete all files inside and folder name with `Notepad++` See below Paths

> C:\Program Files\
>
> C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\Application Data\

- Make sure everything are deleted. Restart your System and Install Notepad++ latest version again.